# updating part of string in c++

Tags: c++, string, updating

Is there any way to update the part of a `string` by passing it in a function?

```
std::string str = "hello world";
```

I want to reverse part of the string for example from index 4 to 8.

I have a function that reverses a string from start index to end index. How I can pass the string from index 4 to 8 to that function so that it will be updated automatically in the `str` string.

Comment: What's the declaration of your "reverse function"?

Comment: post the code that you have...

Comment: Study carefully http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

```
std::string str = "hello world";
std::reverse ( str.begin() + 4, str.begin() + 8 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that takes begin/end iterators. See, for example [std::reverse()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/). Usage example for std::vector is on the same page.

Comment: @Madu, you can actually use `std::reverse()` instead of writing new function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the string by reference:

```
void foo( std::string & inputString )
{
  //anything you do here will directly affect the string passed.
}
```

For example:

```
void foo( std::string & str )
{
    str.append("World!");
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "Hello, ";
    foo(a);
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

will print out "Hello, World!". Another choice is to pass the begin and end iterators of the string. A lot of `std` functions work like that.